# Laravel - Getting Current Month and Year only

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am new to Laravel I'm just learning new things, but as for my project. I need to get the current month and year for today. How can I do it? for what I have now is a label and I want to put the current month and year on the label. Thank you

> Here is my LABEL

```
{{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
```

Comment: How about using jQuery instead of Laravel for month and year?

Comment: How is it gonna work? can you show me a sample code? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always display the current day's month and year, you can use PHP's built-in `date` function. For example, the below will give you a label `November 2018`.

```
{{Form::label('title', date('F Y') )}}
```

See [PHP Documentation on the date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

If you want more powerful manipulation, use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Comment: Hey dude, can I save it to database as STRING ?

Comment: On the other hand? Can I also save it as DATE?

Comment: Since you are using Laravel, you might want to check this page for some handy methods of saving dates. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators. Using `date`, it's just about formatting your date into the default format: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: Sir, @hktang can I also save it to the database as DATE?

Comment: Yes, you can. With Laravel I think it uses DateTime by default. But your own DATE field is of course possible.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library which is available out of the box with Laravel:

```
{{ Form::label('title', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('M, Y') }}
```

You can format using native PHP DateTime [Format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Update:

As @Josh mentioned, you can also use the laravel helper [now()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-now)

> The now function creates a new Illuminate\Support\Carbon instance for the current time

```
{{ Form::label('title', now()->format('M, Y') }}
```

Comment: Hey dude, I thought it was gonna work but error was found how to solve this one? Class 'Carbon' not found

Comment: @SummerWinter add use Carbon\Carbon to the top of your file above your class declaration

Answer (score 2):

Laravel come with a prebuilt component to manage Date, and it's know under the name [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) it have many method to access and modify `DateTime` php object. To access the month and year of the current day you can access the property `month` and `year` directly on the Carbon Object

```
$today = Carbon::now();
$today->month; // retrieve the month
$today->year; // retrieve the year of the date
```

In you Controller you can pas the `$today` object to the method use to render the related view with purpose to have access to that object on a get value of attribute that you want to show in the label field

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
{{ Form::label('title', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('F Y') }}
```